# Selecting entire column after searching for header name

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to teach myself VBA and am very new to this. Stackoverflow has been an awesome resource so far so I figured I'd ask it here.

What I want it to do is find the cell named "Reference," then copy the column below it.

For some reason I can't find this anywhere online and figured I'd bite the bullet and submit a question.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions get more attention if you include your current code.  Are you able to find the "reference" cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "cell named". If the cell is in fact named "Reference" (i.e. if you have renamed the range of cell `A1` to `Reference`, you can then copy the cell below this by using the offset method:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("Reference").Offset(1, 0).Copy
```

If you instead are searching for a cell with the value "Reference" you can find this cell and copy the cell blow this by using a method like this (note that if there are multiple cells that meet the search criteria, it will copy the cell below the last found cell):

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set c = .Find("Reference", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(c.Address).Offset(1, 0).Copy
    End If
End With
```

If you want to copy an entire column below a specific cell, you can do something in line of the following code. In this case it will copy all of used cells below the cell `C7`.

```
Sub CopyColumnBelow()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("C7")

    ActiveSheet.Range(r, ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, r.Column).End(xlUp).Address).Copy
End Sub
```

Hope you can use this to move forward learning Excel VBA.

Comment: Beautiful, that helped me very much. Appreciated!